# Jquery Greensock Tweenlite - same object different effect different duration

Tags: jquery, slide, gsap

I am making a slide banner with jquery and greensock tweenlite/timelinemax.
I have some code below, wanna know how can I write it in a better way?

e1, e2, e3, e4 is div with image and opacity=0.
For example, I want '.e1' fly from y:0 to y:-90 in 5 secand I want '.e1' fade in in 0.5sec at the same time.

Below are the code by me, hope somebody can optimize it:

```
var tweenA = TweenLite.to(".e1", 5, {top:"-90px", ease:Linear.easeNone});
tweenA = TweenLite.to(".e1", 2, {opacity:1});

tweenA = TweenLite.to(".e2", 5.5, {top:"-70px", delay:4, ease:Linear.easeNone, onComplete:function(){objHide(".e1")} });
tweenA = TweenLite.to(".e2", 2, {opacity:1, delay:4});

tweenA = TweenLite.to(".e3", 6, {top:"-80px", delay:8, ease:Linear.easeNone});
tweenA = TweenLite.to(".e3", 2, {opacity:1, delay:8, onComplete:function(){objHide(".e2")}});
tweenA = TweenLite.to(".e3", 2, {opacity:0, delay:12});
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using a `Timeline` instead of separated `TweenLite`. A better code would be something like this:

```
TweenLite.defaultEase = Linear.easeNone;
var tl = new TimelineMax({paused: true});

tl
.to(".e1", 5, {top:"-90px"})
.to(".e1", 2, {opacity:1})
.to(".e2", 5.5, {top:"-70px", delay:4, onComplete:objHide, onCompleteParams: [".e1"]})
.to(".e2", 2, {opacity:1, delay:4})
.to(".e3", 6, {top:"-80px", delay:8 })
.to(".e3", 2, {opacity:1, delay:8, onComplete:objHide, onCompleteParams: [".e3"]})
.to(".e3", 2, {opacity:0, delay:12});
tl.play();
```

If the different tweens don't need to run one after the other you could add some labels, like this:

```
tl
.add('start')
.to(".e1", 5, {top:"-90px"}, 'start')
.to(".e1", 2, {opacity:1}, 'start')
.to(".e2", 5.5, {top:"-70px", delay:4, onComplete:objHide, onCompleteParams: [".e1"]}, 'start')
.add('secondPart')
.to(".e2", 2, {opacity:1, delay:4}, 'secondPart')
.to(".e3", 6, {top:"-80px", delay:8 }, 'secondPart')
.to(".e3", 2, {opacity:1, delay:8, onComplete:objHide, onCompleteParams: [".e3"]}, 'secondPart')
.to(".e3", 2, {opacity:0, delay:12}, 'secondPart');
```

`tl.play();`

You can then adjust the whole animation speed with the: `tl.timeScale(2)`(in this case it doubles the whole tl speed).

Hope it helps.